# Instantiate classes in python from list of strings

Tags: python

I have found answers on stackoverflow that seem to be getting at my question, but I can't find something that I have been able to get to work. I have a really big list of strings like this:

```
db = ['a','b','c']
```

And I want to instantiate a class for each string, where unique strings would be the variable names:

```
a = MyClass()
b = MyClass()
c = MyClass()
```

I thought to convert the strings to variables, but this doesn't seem advisable from some answers I'm finding here on SO.

What is the best way of going about this?

Comment: use a `dictionary` ?

Comment: Just use a dict with the strings as keys and the class instances as values. That's pretty much how Python namespaces work anyway.

Comment: @letsc I have read that in a number of posts, but I'm not sure how to do this. Should the values all be an instantiation of a class with the same variable name? Like this: `{'a':x, 'b':x, 'c':x}`

Comment: You want something like `instances = dict((k, MyClass()) for k in db)`. Or a dict comprehension, if you're on at least 2.7: `instances = {k: MyClass() for k in db}`.

Answer (score 1):

### I do not recommend this

You can add the names to the globals

```
names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
globals().update({name: MyClass() for name in names})
print(a)
```

or locals dictionary:

```
def myfunc():
    names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    locals().update({name: MyClass() for name in names})
    print(a)
```

### Using a dict

Better would be just to use a dict to store your `MyClass`-instances:

```
names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
data = {k: MyClass() for k in names}
print(data['a'])
```